# Check if flutter-intl translation exists and use it

Tags: flutter, dart, translation, flutter-intl

I use flutter-intl to translate my app. I use protocol-buffers to communicate with other users. In the protocol buffer is an enum, e.g. blue, red, yellow.
Now I want to translate the value of the enum and fallback to the enum variant name, if the translation does not exist.
I think something like this:

```
String enumValStr = enumVal.toString();
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate(enumValStr, enumValStr);
```

The first would be the String I want to translate, the second a fallback.
Is there such a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a simple switch-case. This way nobody removes a needed translation without the build passing, also `flutter-lints` complains if an item is missing.